# SSRS regenerate the report

Tags: .net, reporting-services

I'm accessing reports from an SSRS server using URL access. I generate the report links dynamically in my web app and everything is working fine. Except for that the reports are not refreshed automatically. I think the server serves all subsequent request from cache. The reports are refreshed only when a different report is generated(diferent DB values for the report).

This is how I'm accessing them.

```
http://seivmedevrs01.ctc.seic.com/ReportServer?%2fIMS%2fDublin%2fKII%2fDev%2fKeyInvestorInformation&rc:toolbar=false&Id=13
```

I wonder if there is a parameter that tells the server to allways

Comment: Can you give some more information on what you mean by "generate the reports dynamically"? Are you generating the report definitions? If so, I wouldn't even go to the reporting server, there's a microsoft control toolkit with accompanying libraries that allows you to avoid this. See this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251671%28en-US,VS.80%29.aspx.

Comment: No, I'm generating only the report URL LINKS dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this parameter to the URL:

```
rs:ClearSession=true
```

Giving you a URL of:

```
http://seivmedevrs01.ctc.seic.com/ReportServer?%2fIMS%2fDublin%2fKII%2fDev%2fKeyInvestorInformation&rc:toolbar=false&Id=13&rs:ClearSession=true
```

[Source](http://www.jasonfollas.com/blog/archive/2009/02/25/how-to-force-ssrs-to-use-latest-data.aspx)